# Updating EndDates with StartDate on next line with same ID in temporal tables

Tags: sql-server

While doing some checks in our SQL Server temporal (system-versioning) tables, we found a bunch of duplicate records writing in due to a data type issue in the ingestion process - this meant tables of 3 million records were sitting at like 30 million records.

We removed all the duplicates in the system versioned table, however, we now have a situation where the EndTimes are not equal to the start time of the next actual change.

I have tested multiple different ways to update it however the slow-running nature of the update is causing severe headaches. currently, I am using a cte which works perfectly however as mentioned far too slow on tables with a couple of million records - any advice on another way/method that may be better/more performance driven?

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT
        t_base.SysStartTime, t_base.SysEndTime, t_next.SysStartTime AS NextStartTime
    FROM 
        dbo.SAMPLE t_base
    CROSS APPLY 
        (SELECT TOP 1 SysStartTime
         FROM dbo.SAMPLE
         WHERE OID = t_base.OID
           AND SysStartTime >= t_base.SysEndTime
         ORDER BY SysEndTime ASC) t_next
)
UPDATE cte 
SET SysEndTime = NextStartTime
WHERE SysEndTime != NextStartTime
```

Please note the query does indeed cross apply back on itself in order to check the next rows start date and apply accordingly

I have also attempted adding an index on the `OID`, `SysStartTime`, and `SysEndTime`.

Comment: I could be mistaken, as this delves into the nuts and bolts of SQL, but if you're going through millions of records, a CTE is going to be very inefficient as it has to run that each time. Perhaps try dumping your CTE data into a `#TEMP` table, then join it with the table you want to update. You could even add an index to the temp table depending on what all is included in your data.

Comment: You may have some success with the `LEAD` function, if your version of SQL Server has it available.

Comment: Thanks @jw11432 will run a test and revert

Comment: @BrianStork interesting thought, may remove the need for the cross apply which is where the issue lies, let me give it a test and revert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the LEAD function as proposed by Brian Stork definitely has a major positive impact and will be using this solution:

```
SELECT OID, SysStartTime, SysEndTime,
LEAD (SysStartTime,1) OVER (PARTITION BY OID ORDER BY SysEndTime ASC) AS NextStartTime
FROM dbo.SAMPLE
```